# iterate dynamic array in perl cgi script

Tags: jquery, arrays, perl, cgi

I pass via jquery

```
$.ajax({
    'type' : 'POST',
    'data' : { 
               'foo': {
                   'foo1':'bar1,
                   'foo2':'bar2'
               }
            },
    'async' : false,
    'global' : false,
    'url' : "path/to/script.pl",
    'dataType' : "json",
    'success' : function(data) {
        json = data;
    },
    'error' : function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Request Failed: " + textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

to my cgi script.

HTML Parameter: `foo%5Bfoo1%5D=bar1&foo%5Bfoo2%5D=bar2`

I can't use `foo` as an array by using `$cgi->param('foo[]')`

> CGI::param called in list context from package main line 30, this can lead to vulnerabilities. See the warning in "Fetching the value or values of a single named parameter

i seems that all array elements are hardcoded into parameter like 'foo[foo1]'.

is it possible to get dynamic access?

Output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper scalar $cgi->Vars();`

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'use_tempfile' => 1,
                 '.fieldnames' => {},
                 '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
                 '.parameters' => [
                                    'foo[foo1]',
                                    'foo[foo2]'
                                  ],
                 'escape' => 1,
                 'param' => {
                              'foo[foo2]' => [
                                               'bar2'
                                             ],
                              'foo[foo1]' => [
                                               'bar¹'
                                             ]
                            }
               }, 'CGI' );
```

Comment: How do you pass that to your CGI script? That's not a perl data type, it looks like a json object.

Comment: yes, its json. i use jquery $.ajax to pass it

Comment: Think a little more code might be needed to figure out what's going on. I'll also point out - `CGI` is deprecated, although I appreciate that might not be something you can control.

Comment: $VAR1 = bless( { '.parameters' => [
   'foo[foo1]',
   'foo[foo2]' ],
'use_tempfile' => 1,
   '.charset' => 'ISO-8859-1',
   '.fieldnames' => {},
    'param' => {
        'foo[foo2]' => [
             'bar2'
                              ],
            'foo[foo1]' => [
                                'bar¹'
                                  ]
     },
   'escape' => 1
    }, 'CGI' );

Comment: In your input there is no `'foo[]'` parameter, just `'foo[foo2]'` and `'foo[foo1]'`. Are you sure, jquery is sending in json format?

Comment: ... these things are probably best included in the question for clarity.

Comment: all i want do do is to fetch over foo with dynamic array fieldnames

Comment: Json key value pairs should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: @MegaChroniX  how u want dynamic acess could you give example?

Comment: i want to do something like:

my @foo = $cgi->param("foo");

foreach my $a (@$foo){
if ($a eq 'bar1'){ next; }
print " and so on...";
}

but cgi or jquery changed my json-foo-array into single parmeters foo[foo1] and foo[foo2], so i can't access foo[].

Answer (score 2):

You have to send data as json string

```
    'data' : JSON.stringify({
               'foo': {
                   'foo1':'bar1',
                   'foo2':'bar2'
               }
            }),
```

and at the server side convert string to native perl structure,

```
use JSON;
my $data = decode_json( $cgi->param('keywords') );
```

Comment: oh sorry, copy paste error form renaming into foo ..my bad

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a perl-own method to convert json "arrays" back to real arrays or hash.

So I did it by my own:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new();    
my %hash = ();

foreach my $a ($cgi->param())
{
    if($a =~ /^([\w\-]+)\[(.*)\]/)  #TODO multidimensional
    {
        $hash{$1}{$2} = $cgi->param($a);
    }
    else
    {
        $hash{$a} = $cgi->param($a);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's best not to name a hash `%hash` -- the `%` says it's a hash, and you should use the identifier to say something about its purpose

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want something like this.First the jquery which sends the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing ajax</title> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#test").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'ajax1.cgi',
                            data: {'foo': { 
                                            'foo1':'bar1', 
                                            'foo2':'bar2'
                                 }
                                 },
                            success: function(res) {

                                                        $( ".demo" ).append("your first var is: " + res.foo1+"<br />");
                                                        $( ".demo" ).append("your second var is  :"+res.foo2);

                                                    },
                            error: function() {alert("did not work");}
                    });
                })

            })



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button id="test" >Testing</button>
        <div class="demo" >
        </div>
    </body>
```

The cgi script is ajax1.cgi. Note that the response is sent in json format.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON; #if not already installed, just run "cpan JSON"
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper; 


my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header('application/json;charset=UTF-8');

#my $id = $cgi->param('foo[]');
my @cgivars=$cgi->param; #get all key value of param in array
my $cgivar1="Not defined";
my $cgivar2="Not defined";
foreach my $a(@cgivars){
 if($cgi->param($a) eq 'bar1'){
       $cgivar1="bar1"; #means do whatever you like to do here
       }
else{
       $cgivar2="bar2"; #same here etc
}
}
#print Dumper scalar $cgi->Vars();
#convert  data to JSON
my $op = JSON -> new -> utf8 -> pretty(1);
my $json = $op -> encode({
    foo1=>$cgivar1,
    foo2=>$cgivar2
});
print $json;
```